# How perform drag zoom with puppeteer for emulated devices

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, puppeteer

Has anyone managed to simulate a drag zoom interaction with puppeteer when the page is in emulated device mode. To do this as a user, you hold down the SHIFT key while dragging the mouse.

Unfortunately the following doesn't work

```
const cx = 160;
const cy = 284;
await page.mouse.move(cx, cy);
await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
await page.mouse.down();
await page.mouse.move(cx, cy - 300, {steps: 300});
await page.mouse.up();
await page.keyboard.up('Shift');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the puppeteer team did not add any of such feature, I confirmed it last year https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2000

Answer (score 1):

According to this conversation on [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2000), they are not planning to add such feature. I'll quote their response,

> I don't like adding puppeteer-level API for the WebPlatform's events.
>   Puppeteer's clicks are way different to the WebPlatform's
>   document.createEvent; having them as the only first-class API
>   emphasizes that they're the recommended way to click things on the
>   page.
>
> I'd recommend to use a set of helper methods to cover your needs.

However you can do it this way,

```
await this._client.send('Input.dispatchMouseEvent', {
      type: 'mousePressed',
      button: this._button,
      x: this._x,
      y: this._y,
      modifiers: this._keyboard._modifiers,
      clickCount: (options.clickCount || 1)
});
```

Here is another code snippet to trigger one small mouse event (to be used with .evaluate function).

```
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```